# How can I put link to offline html page?

Tags: html

How can I put link to offline html page?

```
   <a href="C:\Users\Me\Desktop\of\test.html">Test</a>
```

Why this doesn't work in my case?

Answer (score 4):

```
<a href="file:///C:\Users\Me\Desktop\of\test.html">Test</a>
```

Use file:/// preceding path

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to use absolute links? Wouldn't it be easier for you just to use relative links? Something like this:

```
<a href="test.html">Test</a>
```

Still, if you really do need to use absolute links, this would be the way to do it:

```
<a href="file:///C:/Users/Me/Desktop/of/test.html">Test</a>
```

(notice the backslash is changed to forward slash).